# Struggling with the neuter gender when translating this movie quote

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, gender, neuter

I'm trying to translate, "If it can bleed, we can kill it," but I'm really confused about how the neuter gender would work in this case.

The closest version I got to thus far has been "Si potest cruentare, possumus occidere"...but it doesn't sound right to me.

P.S. Whoops. The original quote from *Predator* is, "If it bleeds, we can kill it."  That would make my translation something more like, "Si sanguinat, possumus occidere." Does this sound a bit more reasonable?

P.P.S. And I guess my first version could be "Si sanguinare potest, interficere possumus"?

Answer (score 10):

I would get rid of the if…then construction here, and rely on the verbs: **quod sanguinat perit**, "that which [can] bleed, [can] perish". This is a bit less explicit about who's doing the killing than the English, but makes for a snappier motto.

Comment: Why *quid* instead of *quod*?

Comment: @cmw Good point, _quod_ is probably better here.

Comment: @Draconis I am very happy with this answer! I am, however, still curious how this might be rendered if we did choose to use the less fancy phrasing. As I wrote above, the neuter in Latin is super confusing to me and I was hoping to see some examples. :) /grateful /friendly